# Firebase Database permissions denied after initial account creation/login

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm having a problem in firebase for unity.  After logging in or creating a new account, I am getting database permission errors when trying to write to areas of the database that should be writeable based on the uid of the account that was just logged in/created.  But I am getting a permissions error:

Firebase.Database.DatabaseException: Firebase Database error: Permission denied

Here are my database rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    "unlimited_enabled": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid == auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the `Task` that fails with the exception above:

```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference.Child("unlimited_enabled").Child(FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser.UserId).SetValueAsync(true);
```

If the user is already (automatically) logged into an account from a previous session when they startup the app, then the above task succeeds.  To me this seems like a bug in firebase, but maybe I am missing something.

I thought maybe there was a delay between signing in/creating an account and when auth.uid is updated, but I have waited several minutes and it still does not work.  But as soon as I restart the app, it works.

For login I am just using:

```
auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential)
```

And for creating an account, I am using:

```
auth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I am using firebase for Unity.  That's C#, not javascript.  Following the docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/password-auth

Comment: *What* seems like a bug?

Comment: Can you post the errors you are getting? Are you getting errors on read or write?

Comment: I posted the exception above: Firebase.Database.DatabaseException: Firebase Database error: Permission denied.  I am getting an error on write.  The call that fails is in my post.

Comment: It seems like a bug that I don't get the exception if I try the write to the database after the user is automatically authenticated at startup, but I do get the exception if I try the write to the database after an explicit login/account creation

Comment: Basically it seems like auth.uid that I used in the database rule is not correct (not updated?) after an account creation or a login